# How to show a website using webview_flutter package correctly?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies

I have tried to write a code that shows my website on flutter app, at the bottom bar there are two buttons which can do forward and backward. But the WebView package show me an error. im using Flutter 3.7.5 and vsCode as my IDE.Here is my code.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('keeTube'),
        ),
        body: WebView (
          initialUrl: "https://keetube.netlify.app/",
          onWebViewCreated: (controller) => _controller.complete(controller),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, right: 20),
            child: ButtonBar(
              children: [
                navigationButton(
                    Icons.chevron_left, (controller) => _goBack(controller)),
                navigationButton(
                    Icons.chevron_right, (controller) => _goForward(controller))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget navigationButton(
      IconData icon, Function(WebViewController) onPressed) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: _controller.future,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<WebViewController> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  icon,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () => onPressed(snapshot.data!));
          } else {
            return Container();
          }
        });
  }

  void _goBack(WebViewController controller) async {
    final canGoBack = await controller.canGoBack();
    if (canGoBack) {
      controller.goBack();
    }
  }

  void _goForward(WebViewController controller) async {
    final canGoForward = await controller.canGoForward();
    if (canGoForward) {
      controller.goForward();
    }
  }
}
```

it got me this error on "Webview" key word

The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WebView'

1. I installed dependency on pubspec.yaml file

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  webview_flutter: ^4.2.0
```

```
[webapp] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in webapp...
Resolving dependencies...
  async 2.10.0 (2.11.0 available)
  characters 1.2.1 (1.3.0 available)
  collection 1.17.0 (1.17.1 available)
  js 0.6.5 (0.6.7 available)
  lints 2.0.1 (2.1.0 available)
  matcher 0.12.13 (0.12.16 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.2.0 (0.5.0 available)
  meta 1.8.0 (1.9.1 available)
  path 1.8.2 (1.8.3 available)
  source_span 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)
  test_api 0.4.16 (0.5.2 available)
Got dependencies!
```

2. And I changed  minSdkVersion into 19

```
defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.webapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

So if anyone can tell me how to fix it as showing a website.

Answer (score 0):

You can create WebView using following code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(
  const MaterialApp(
    home: WebViewApp(),
   ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
 const WebViewApp({super.key});

 @override
 State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
 }

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
 late final WebViewController controller;

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
   controller = WebViewController()
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
  ..setNavigationDelegate(
  NavigationDelegate(
  onProgress: (int progress) {
   // Update loading bar.
   },
  onPageStarted: (String url) {},
  onPageFinished: (String url) {},
  onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
  onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
  if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
  return NavigationDecision.prevent;
  }
  return NavigationDecision.navigate;
  },
  ),
  )
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://keetube.netlify.app/'));
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text('keeTube'),
   ),
   body: WebViewWidget(
    controller: controller,
   ),
  );
 }
}
```

For more details you can check this https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter